# arranging angular components from bottom using css/html

Tags: html, css, angular

I have following arrangement for display of few angular components:

```
    <div class="my-parent">
      <my-child-1></my-child-1>
      <div class="style-2">
        <my-child-2></my-child-2>
      </div>
      <div class="style-3">
        <my-child-3 style="bottom: 10px;position: absolute;"></my-child-3>
      </div>
    </div>

    .style-2 {
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 368px;
    }

    .style-3 {
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 301px;
    }
```

My objective is that my-child-3 is at the bottom, with my-child-2 right at its top. my-child-2 and my-child-1 are interchanged based on some condition. Also, I want that height of my-child-1 to be max 301px, and to have a scrollbar if content exceeds this.

Issue I am facing is that if my-child-3 content is less than 301px then my-child-2 is not sitting right at its top, and there is a gap between two. I understand that as I have fixed my-child-3's parent div's  height at 301px, that much space(301-actual content height) is left empty, and only after it parent div of my-child-2 starts.

But I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: checkout css flex

Comment: use flex-direction as reverse if all you wanna do is `arrange component from bottom`

Comment: Hi, it does make a difference. But both my-child-3 and my-child-2 starts from bottom, hence my-child-3 overlaps my-child-2 partially.